# Reverse proxy and server redirect

Tags: redirect, iis, reverse-proxy

I have Angular app in IIS, which is configured to work as reverse proxy, directing requests to node backend running in same server. From node there is a redirect third party login. The problem is that when trying to redirect to this third party login page **from** my node backend, something adds to URL my apps URL like:

```
myapp.com/thirdpartyurl
```

even though it should only be:

```
thirdpartyurl
```

Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Check who generates the wrong URL.

Comment: Are you using a relative path in your reverse proxy site which is hosted as a virtual application? If so the path will be misunderstood. Please check whether the added segement is your application name.

Comment: The added segment is my website name, I have app running as a website. It seems that it adds site url to the location header that it has as a redirective response from backend. Now trying to stop my site doing that.

Comment: It is approciated if you could post your reverse proxy setting like URL rewrite.

Comment: Found the solution: in IIS  there is "Application Request Routing Cache" and there "Server Proxy Settings", where  and "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" checkbox needs to be unchecked. Thank you very much for your help, you pushed me to right direction in analyzing the cause!